# How to fix getrowcount() in netbeans?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

My table in java is connected to mysql. It retrieves data in the table. but when i specified getrowcount() it shows 0 rows in system.out.print. pls help, our project deadline is on 3rd june.

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    model.setRowCount(0);
try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project","root","tiger");
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    if(ch1.isSelected()){
    String query = "Select * from details where name like '"+d2.getText()+"%';";
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    System.out.print(table.getRowCount());
    }
    if(table.getRowCount() == 0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No records found");
    }
    while(rs.next()){
        int id;
        id = rs.getInt("userid");
        String name = rs.getString("name");
        String gender = rs.getString("gender");
        String dob = rs.getString("dob");
        String phno = rs.getString("phoneno");
        String doj = rs.getString("joindate");
        String doe = rs.getString("exitdate");
        model.addRow(new Object[]{id,name,gender,dob,phno,doj,doe});
    }
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error");
}
            d1.setText("");
            d2.setText("");
            d3.setSelectedItem("");
            d4.setText("");
            d5.setText("");
            d6.setText("");
            d7.setText("");
            update.setEnabled(false);
            delete.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Where is table declared ? I can not see anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Please check below what does getRowCount() gives you

[image]

You can refer the below link for more clarification
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getRowCount--